# How to read a String array members one by one using RxJava and call a network API for the first result?

Tags: java, android, arrays, rx-java, rx-android

I have an array of String, for instance:

> cities = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "Berlin", "e"}

I want to call my weather api using its members as parameter one by one and take the first result which cause no exception and has a weather result (in another word, it is the name of a city!).

I have tried this but it stops at the first exception and do not continue with other array members!

```
Observable.from(cities)
            .flatMap(interactor::loadWeather)
            .filter(weatherCurrent -> weatherCurrent != null)
            .first()
            .observeOn(scheduler.mainThread())
            .subscribe(...
```

The priority is with the first result and I want to quit calling using other members.

> According to the sample String array the api should call with `a` as city param and return nothing, call with `b` as city and return nothing, but as `Berlin` it would return the weather info, and do not call using `e`.

any idea?

Comment: There is an overload to `flatMap` which let's you delay errors from any of the participating Observable.

Comment: Didn't solved the problem 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onErrorResumeNext` and `concatMap`:

```
Observable.from(cities)
        .concatMap(city -> interactor
           .loadWeather(city)
           .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()))
        .filter(weatherCurrent -> weatherCurrent != null)
        .first()
        .observeOn(scheduler.mainThread())
        .subscribe(...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really works and you saved my day. 